# Passing data between Vuefiles/Vuecomponents

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I try to create some admin panel in vue2.js with some charts and tabelles.

In my overview.vue (the page with all the content in it, like charts,...) i collect some data from the backend via axios.get calls. The same data i want to use in other vue components, like a pieChart.js or a vueTabels.vue.

Is there any way to do this? I read about props: [] to use data dynamically in a child component.

Follow a part of my overview.vue:

```
  <h2>Groups overview</h2> 
  <div v-if="groupCount > 0">
    <li v-for="group in groups">
      <p><b>Group name:</b> {{group.name}}, <b>Group id:</b> {{group.groupId}}</p>

<pie-chart></pie-chart>

<script>
import Mixins from "../mixins.js";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookie from "../js/Cookie.js";
import Config from "../js/Config.js";

import PieChart from "@/components/PieChart.js";

export default {
  name: "overview",
  mixins: [Mixins],
  components: {
    PieCount,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      groups: [],
      groupCount: "",

    };
  },

>   mounted: function() {
>     this.groups = []
>     this.getGroups();
> 
>   methods: {

>     getGroups: function() {
>       axios
>         .get(Config.URL +"groups", {
>         })
>         .then(response => {
>           this.groups = response.data.payload;
>           this.groupCount = this.groups.length;
>         })
>         .catch(e => {
>           this.errors.push(e);
>         });
>     },
```

The data groupCount and groups[] i want to have dynamically in my other component, like the PieChart.js.

Snipped of PieCount.js:

```
import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs';
import axios from "axios";
import Cookie from "../js/Cookie.js";
import Config from "../js/Config.js";

export default Pie.extend({
name: "PieChart",
props: ['groupCount', 'groups']


data() {
    return {
        options: {

        }
    }
},

mounted: function() {

this.renderChart({
                labels: ['Group', "Groups"],
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: ['#FC2525', '#05CBE1'],
                    data: [groups, groupCount]
                }, ],
            }, { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }, )
```

If i do it this way, the data groups and groupCount in my PieChart.js is always undefined.

Has anyone a solution to pass data between js-Files or VueComponents? The way i solve this problem till now is to do the same axios requests and data fetching in my PieChart.js but i hope there is another solution.

Comment: props is your solution to this problem.

Comment: But im using props as you can see in the snippets above. Whats wrong with them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the props down in your template

`<pie-chart :groupCount="groupCount" :groups="groups"></pie-chart>`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props

Comment: You have my greatest thanks! :)
It works now, really great. Only thing i stucked here abit was the asyc. loading of data. Fixed this with boolean variables. Initial them with false and set to true when axios data are fetched. Then <div v-if="boolVariable"><pie-chart: groupCount="groupCount", .../>.